# What is the default base-package for Spring MVC's context:component-scan?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

If I have my controller package and dao package directly under /src, what is the base-package I need to configure in the following line of code?

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.students" />`

Answer (score 1):

Use comma-separated package names.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller, dao"/>
```